# Polymorphic nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

this is the first time working with polymorphic associations. I have a picture model that belongs to a user model and a scoreboard model. The migration for the picture model is given below.

```
class CreatePictures < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :pictures do |t|
      t.string :picture
      t.references :imageable, index: true, polymorphic: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_foreign_key :pictures, :imageables
  end

  add_index :pictures, :imageable_id
  # add index on the pictues table on the imageable_id column
end
```

The belongs_to and has_one associations code is given below.

```
class Scoreboard < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :picture, as: :imageable
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :picture, as: :imageable
end

class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
end
```

The `scoreboard_picture` resource is nested inside the `scoreboards` resource.

```
resources :scoreboards do 
   resources :scoreboard_picture, only: [:create, :destroy, :new]
end
```

I have `scoreboard_picture` controller with the following new method.

```
class ScoreboardPictureController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @scoreboard = Scoreboard.find(params[:scoreboard_id])
        @picture = @scoreboard.build_picture
    end
```

`New` Action

```
 <%= form_for([@scoreboard, @picture], url: scoreboards_picture_path, html: {multipart: true}) do |f| %>
 <%= f.file_field :picture, accept: 'image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png', id: "files" %>
 <% end %>
```

I have implemented nested routes before and it hasn't given me any problems. However, I keep getting the following error.

```
 undefined local variable or method `scoreboards_picture_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fa4c054f490>:0x00000007574700>
```

I think it has something to do with polymorphic associations. I tried providing the URL in the form. It still doesn't work. I read a few other posts on this question and tried using what worked for them, still getting the error. I am pretty sure my new method is correct. I've been stuck on this for a while. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It probably needs to be `scoreboard_picture_path`.  You can confirm this by running `rake routes` and looking at the left column.

Comment: it should be `scoreboards_scoreboard_picture_path`

Comment: @PardeepDhingra I tried that previously and it didn't work. I tried it now as well. Not sure whats the problem

Comment: @dwenzel I tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: Running rake routes helped. It was new_scoreboard_scoreboard_picture_path. Thanks for the help!